# Footnote or internal reference?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Within a question or answer is it possible to write a footnote?

For example, if I use a tricky term, for many readers, some of them will
understand it at first reading, but some others might prefer a
correct explanation. To do this within web pages or written technical
documents I use footnotes.

Is this possible within StackExchange?

If not, could this feature be added?

What is the relevant StackExchange group wher to ask this question?

Comment: Any bug report and feature enhancement request on any per-site mets does get picked up by stack exchange. We can move it to the main meta if/when it needs consensus from multiple sites.

Comment: Thank you. But I'll let this feature request open since it might be usefull on other groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this a few times using the built-in superscript. For example:

> This is an example of additional information<sup>1</sup> being added to a post.
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup> Here is the additional information.</sup>

<sub>Source:</sub>

```
This is an example of additional information<sup>1</sup> being added to a post.
```

```
<sup><sup>1</sup> Here is the additional information.</sup>
```

This seems to work pretty well for most situations.

Comment: Thank you very much :).
This is nice enough for my actual need.

Answer (score -1):

On MacOS, I’ve used Unicode Hex Input to enter them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts